# my udpserver program is interrupted in the function do_use_service of boost::asio when execute the constructor function,i wonder why and how to edit?

Tags: c++, boost

i use the vs debug and it was interrupted and have a exception when the stack calls execution_context::service* service_registry::do_use_service() function in the
service_registry.ipp,

```
execution_context::service* service_registry::do_use_service(
    const execution_context::service::key& key,
    factory_type factory, void* owner)
{
  boost::asio::detail::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
  ...
```

the final interrupt function is at this function in win_mutex.hpp

```
  void lock()
  {
    ::EnterCriticalSection(&crit_section_);
  }
```

i wonder why it was interrupted and how to edit my UDPServer class, i want the io_context varable to be as a member of my UDPServer class,does it work?i want to use the object only pass the host and port

my header

```
#ifndef UDPSERVER_H
#define UDPSERVER_H
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
namespace util {
    class UDPServer : public std::enable_shared_from_this<UDPServer> {
    public:
        enum { UDP_PORT = 18400 };
        UDPServer(const std::string& host, short port);
        ~UDPServer();
        void start_receive();
        //void setObserver(std::weak_ptr<WebSocket::Observer> observer) noexcept;
        void start();

    private:
        boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
        boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
        // 接受ip和端口
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
        // 设置一个指针，参考util::WebSocket
        //std::weak_ptr<WebSocket::Observer> observer_;
        enum { max_length = 1024 };
        char data_[max_length];
        bool start_ = false;
    };
} // namespace util
#endif
```

the .cpp file

```
#include "UdpServerByUsingBoostAsio.h"

namespace util {
    UDPServer::UDPServer(const std::string& host, short port)
        :io_context_(),socket_(io_context_, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port))
    {
        printf("debug:UDPServer Constructor");
        //start_receive();
        start_receive();
        io_context_.run();
    }
    UDPServer::~UDPServer() {
        socket_.close();
    }
    void UDPServer::start_receive() {
        printf("debug:UDPServer start_receive");
        socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
            [this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes_recvd) {
                printf("debug:UDPServer handle_receive");
                if (!error) {
                    printf(" Received message from %s,%d,%s", sender_endpoint_.address().to_string().c_str(), sender_endpoint_.port(), data_);
                    start_receive();
                }
                else {
                    printf("error:UDPServer handle_receive,ec_msg:%s", error.message().c_str());
                }});
    }
    void UDPServer::start() {
        start_ = true;
        //start_receive();
        //io_context_.run();
    }
} // namespace util
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "UdpServerByUsingBoostAsio.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    try {
        shared_ptr<std::thread> netAccess_ = std::make_shared<std::thread>([&] {
            std::shared_ptr<util::UDPServer> ptr1 = std::make_shared<util::UDPServer>("127.0.0.1", util::UDPServer::UDP_PORT);
            ptr1->start();
            });
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    printf("%-> modelId(%s)", "caiji", "jiuzhe");
    return 0;
}
```